# Thermal expansion and thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics

Isn't thermal expansion and laws of thermodynamics contradictory? 
Gas expands when heated, but after expansion it cools down.

Answer (score 2):

One of the first things to learn in thermodynamics is the importance of explicitly stating the conditions of a transformation. Speaking of thermal expansion and cooling, without specifying how those processes happen allows almost any answer to be correct or false.

For example, a heated gas expands in a container with a movable wall, **if** the heating makes its pressure higher than the external pressure. The cooling you mention can be due to the expanded gas's energy loss if the environment is at a lower temperature. Still, it is also happening when you make a real gas expanding in a surrounding environment at a lower pressure (like the case of compressed gas in an aerosol can when one presses the nozzle).

It is the variety of possible conditions that may induce the idea of contradiction. Actually, the whole manifold of such different behaviors can be nicely explained by thermodynamics.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume that you think gases don’t obey the first law of thermodynamics. Notice that this law simply states that the change in internal energy(sum of potential and kinetic energies of the particles in that system) of a system($\Delta U$) is equal to the sum of the work done on the system($w$) and the heat energy supplied to the system($q$). $$\Delta U=w+q$$

Notice that the expansion and contraction of gases **do not** disobey this law. For the expansion of the gas notice that the molecules need to move faster(obtain a higher temperature) at a certain pressure to occupy a larger volume so hence the internal energy of the gas(i.e kinetic energy) must increase. So indeed $\Delta U$ is positive and this is because heat energy is supplied to the system, $q$ is positive.

Again as the gas is **allowed** to cool it means it transfers heat from the gas system to the surroundings and hence heat energy moves **out** of the gas system so now $q$ is negative and if no other work is done on the gas the internal energy $\Delta U$ of the gas is negative and hence the gas’s temperature drops.

I am open to clarify further details through edits if you wish to elaborate on your question further.